# Serve a static page if the backend is down

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, static-content

Apache is acting as a frontend to another (Rails) server that is responsible for handling the requests. How can I make Apache return a static maintenance page when the backend is down (or unreachable in the past minutes)?

The current Apache configuration is basically

```
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$   http://backend.example.net:9002/$1  [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /     http://backend.example.net:9002/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom 503 error with [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument).

See: [Apache reverse proxy error page when proxied server is down](https://serverfault.com/questions/266924/apache-reverse-proxy-error-page-when-proxied-server-is-down/266937#266937)